# Ubuntu 20.04 can't shut down and also not able to connect with network

Tags: 20.04

When I start my system it's showing the `initramfs` message. I used the command

`fsck /dev/sd4 -y`

after that, the system opens fine.

I tried to connect to the network. It's connected but not working its showing with the question symbol.

After that I got one more pop-up notification. System problem detected.

Then I run this command `sudo rm /var/crash/*`

After running this command, I can't turn off the system and also I can't  connect to the network. Please help me to fix this.

**Note: WiFi, Ethernet, Bluetooth tethering, USB tethering Nothing is working.**

`When I tried to shutdown it's again coming to the login window`

Comment: if nothing works you most likely have failing hardware that is what Nothing is working means.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstall all the package using this command

`sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`